# Seal marks on a little pot (Characters identified: 吳祥君)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

Can I have help reading what these two marks say? Thank you.

[image: marks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 祥
>
> 吳
>
> 君

Teapot maker called 吳祥君, born in 1966 in [Yixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yixing). You can [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%90%B3%E7%A5%A5%E5%90%9B&rlz=1C1GCEU_en-GBNZ822NZ822&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-pJ2xvfzlAhWB7HMBHRPUDuMQ_AUoAnoECAsQBA&biw=1920&bih=937) this name to get more images of teapots.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seal is on the bottom [link](https://i.imgur.com/9xbjdzU.jpg) ,but the characters are different and don't match with the ones on the lid.